# Visual Webpart-Deployment Issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-web-part

While deploying Visual web part in SharePoint Production Farm consisting of 6 WFE, 2 APP, 2 Distribute Cache servers, we are facing issue.

I am not getting error message just web part is showing "Deploying…" and not getting deployed on all servers.

Scope:Site

**Note**: I am not getting any error message.

Kindly assist in resolving the issue.

We are using SharePoint 2013 environment.

Comment: How are you deploying the web part - Visual Studio, PowerShell, Central Admin?

Comment: You said the solution package is "not getting deployed on all servers". Does that mean it is getting deployed to some servers? If so, which ones?

Comment: I mean,  its just showing Deploying... ., I am first adding webpart using powershell command and then deploying using central admin -farm solutions-deploy

Answer (score 0):

Try following the steps in this TechNet article: [SharePoint 2010 Troubleshooting: Solution deployment stuck on deploying](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21350.sharepoint-2010-troubleshooting-solution-deployment-stuck-on-deploying.aspx).

Even though the title says SharePoint 2010, the content applies to SharePoint 2013.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rob Windsor, Will take downtime and test above provided resolution, will update you..

Comment: Hi Rob, I have removed the solution and will check timer service and admin services..

Comment: Hi Rob Windsor, I have logged-In to all 6 WFE and notified one server is not accessible , and admin service, timer service is UP on remaining 5 WFE, we reported to system admin team for 1 WFE, after that 1 WFE is UP i will try deployment if it works its ok, else i will restart all servers and services. thanks

Comment: Now that WFE1 is UP and services are running, will plan for deployment and restart.

Comment: Hi Windsor, solution got successfully deployed , thank you very much for your support, I had deployed through central admin after adding through powershell.

Comment: Glad I could help